# Why is passenger with Nginx looking for passenger_wsgi.py in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

My conf file looks like

```
root /var/www/root/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/wrappers/ruby;
```

and whenever I curl to the site the error I see in Nginx logs is

```
Cannot stat '/var/www/root/passenger_wsgi.py': Permission denied (errno=13); This error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 4417, running as UID 33) does not have permission to access this file.
```

But this is a rails app and I do not have python.

The passenger gem is installed and the app is deployed in production mode.

Why is it looking for a python file and how do I fix this error?

This is on Linode if it helps and I am using rvm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post it seems like you have not correctly installed passenger for ruby application.

There are options during installation of passenger as to which language you want it to be installed against(node, python, ruby etc).

And now as per the logs shared it seems like it is serving as an app server for python application.

I came across same problem and the only way I found out to make this work was to uninstall passenger and install again(selecting ruby as the ).

Comment: That makes sense. I am going to try again and report back

Comment: i am having the same issue

Comment: Mine was working fine for a long time and recently just checked it and got this error (I don't regularly check this site so am unsure when it started happening). Any ideas why it could've just started doing this without me changing anything? An update on Centos perhaps? (This has Cpanel running which I think does some auto updates)